# Is this question primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion

[Were "Baadshah" and "Phir Bhi Dil Hai Hindustani" well received upon release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/were-baadshah-and-phir-bhi-dil-hai-hindustani-well-received-upon-release)

This question was closed stating it is primarily opinion based. The only reason I could think of is that "flop" and "hit" are two relative terms. So it is really hard to tell if a movie is hit or not. However, I think, we have an intuition or common sense which helps us to differentiate between a flop and a hit.

We wouldn't say "The Dark Knight Rises" is a flop or "Pyaar ka Panchanama" a massive hit. So, IMO, hits and flops have disparities which can be identified easily.

Also the present answer is great with links to the then place of the movie in Indian Box Office and total profit of those movies and that it should be called a hit or flop with respect to contemporary film industry.

So the question should be opened.

Comment: I am agree with you and even posted my reopen vote. Because i don't think its opinion based at all.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think that you can write an objective answer to this based on reviews & box-office takings.

Its no more subjective than many questions relating to plot and analysis.

If I cast an open vote it is final however - so I'll wait to see whether there is an opposing viewpoint before doing so.

Comment: That's exactly the present answer consists of- ranks and business of both the movies in their releasing years.

Answer (score 1):

You ask whether the question is opinion-based, and @iandotkelly answers this well. Your larger question, though, is whether is should be reopened. I think it should (and have voted so).

Libraries (which is what we are creating) are successful because they are in tune with and responsive to their communities. The rules are different for an S/E site for tech people or for gamers, because those communities have different needs and wants. The community of people who watch movies and TVs and then go online to find answers about them are reacting to and trying to appreciate a piece of art. Our job is not to decide what will help them appreciate the art, it's to answer their questions.

I think it is a mistake to refer people to other websites to get their information. While we do not want to replicate imdb, surely there is and will be some overlap. We are trying to build a community of users here, and the more welcoming we are and the more accepting we are of their questions, the more likely they will stay around. The more we send them somewhere else, the more likely they won't bother to come back. Wouldn't it be better to establish ourselves as a one-stop-shop for your movie and TV information needs? If people think they can only ask some types of questions here (changing "closed" to "on-hold" was an improvement, but seeing that 5 people thought your question was bad still feels pretty crummy), they may choose to start their search elsewhere.

This is not a place for open-ended opinion questions or for localized sorts of questions. Beyond that, the more we restrict, the more we turn people away. Trivia questions, identify questions, and difficult-to-categorize questions such as this have value for the person asking and quite possibly for others who happen upon it later.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is not a opinion based question and its answer should be fact based not opinion based. I am not in favor of closing this question and **specially the closing reason is completely wrong**. The existing answer presented by @Flyk is also not a opinion based at all and based on fact. So i think it should be reopened and i have even posted my reopen vote too.